# How to deploy Nuxt.js onto Cpanel v80 - With/Without Entry Point

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

Is there a way to create an entry point for `nuxt.js`? I can't seem to find anything in means of documentation for that. Recently cpanel added support for nodejs hosting [read here...](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Install+a+Node.js+Application#HowtoInstallaNode.jsApplication-Overview) The problem is that this installation requires app.js entry point.

The guide  shows how to deploy a simple http server. Is there any way where instead of yarn start I could use some sort of entry point for nuxt.js??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out.

1. `npx create-nuxt-app {name}` and chose express option
2. copy `server/index.js` to app's root `.\app.js`
3. change the path to `nuxt.config.js` inside `app.js` from '../nuxt.config.js' to './nuxt.config.js'
4. follow the instruction on registering app inside cpanel.

Hope it works. I haven't tested it further but seems to start.
Make sure that you don't have any redirects in `public_html/.htaccess` your app won't be working properly with them.